# Can we use the data loss protection mechanisms from sap.ushell in a standalone UI5 application?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I hope there is a way for either SAPUI5 or OpenUI5 as this would ease the development efforts to implement data loss protection. If there isn't, I would be interested to know the best alternative to implement similar behavior. I was thinking of maybe extending the `sap.f.routing.Router` and checking an application-level dirty flag before handling the navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Before exiting the application, methods:
   https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.71.38/#/api/sap.ui.core.Component/methods/onWindowBeforeUnload and https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.71.38/#/api/sap.ui.core.Component/methods/onWindowUnload
   are worked out in the Сomponent of the application. In this method, you can call the hasPendingChanges method on the OData model to check for unsaved changes and show a dialog for user interaction.
2. You can also look in the direction of drafts, implemented on the BOPF or RAP frameworks. Then the state will be stored on the backend. But this is a global change of concept, which will affect the revision of the implementation of logic in the backend.